# Why is GEF documentation so outdated?

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am trying to implement an application with Graphical Editing Framework GEF. But somehow it seems that the tutorials and the documentations are all very old and outdated.
Is GEF not used anymore or are there good, understandable tutorials out there?

Answer (score 2):

The book mentioned by Matt is now available:
"[The Eclipse Graphical Editing Framwork](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321718380)" by Dan Rubel, Jaime Wren, and Eric Clayberg.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'd agree that GEF documentation isn't great. There is a [book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780321718518) in progress, and you can otherwise piece together information from different places; e.g. [Notes for Starting Out with Eclipse GEF](http://pbwhiteboard.blogspot.com/2010/12/notes-for-starting-out-with-eclipse-gef.html).  Also, even if a tutorial is a few years old, it's not necessarily out of date.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I think I will not use GEF however, since it seems very bloated for what I want to do :/